# What it the fastest way, for four people plus luggage, to Heathrow T2 from King's Cross Station?

Tags: transportation, london, lhr

We (four people and luggage) need to get from King's Cross Station to Heathrow Terminal 2 for a 3:15 pm flight to Shannon.  Our train arrives from Edinburgh at 11:51 am.

What it the fastest way to get there and check in on time for our flight to Ireland?

Comment: How much luggage? One suitcase each? 3 each? And how mobile/active are you?

Comment: There are lots of very good journey planners for London, for example the official TFL one https://www.tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/  - and Citymapper, which also has a great app https://citymapper.com/

Answer (score 9):

Use the Tube? Take the Piccadilly line to Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3 station. [The trip takes about an hour](https://tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/results?IsAsync=true&JpType=publictransport&InputFrom=King%27s+Cross&DataSetsJson=null&Modes=tube%2Cdlr%2Coverground%2Ctflrail%2Cbus%2Criver-bus%2Ctram%2Ccable-car%2Cnational-rail%2Criver-tour&From=King%27s+Cross&FromId=1000129&InputTo=Heathrow+Airport+Terminals+1-3&DataSetsJson=null&Modes=tube%2Cdlr%2Coverground%2Ctflrail%2Cbus%2Criver-bus%2Ctram%2Ccable-car%2Cnational-rail%2Criver-tour&To=Heathrow+Airport+Terminals+1-3&ToId=1000105&TimeIs=departing&Date=20150617&Time=0345&IsMapRequired=False&Mode=tube&Mode=overground&WalkingSpeed=average&JourneyPreference=leastinterchange&InputVia=&DataSetsJson=null&Modes=tube%2Cdlr%2Coverground%2Ctflrail%2Cbus%2Criver-bus%2Ctram%2Ccable-car%2Cnational-rail&Via=&ViaId=&NationalSearch=false&AccessibilityPreference=norequirements&WalkingSpeed=average&MaxWalkingMinutes=40&SavePreferences=false&IsMultipleJourneySelection=true&JourneyType=&IsCycleHireOriginOrDestination=False&OnChosenOptionScreen=False&IsPastWarning=False) and there is service every 10 minutes or so all day.

Comment: is correct, just linking this thread which details why Heathrow Express is a worse choice: you'd need to wait for the Tube to get from KX to Paddington, walk (and it's not a short walk) to HEX, wait for the HEX... won't be faster but it'll much more expensive.

Comment: ...and taking the Tube means that you don't have to change trains anywhere (assuming you get on the right train at Kings Cross), which is useful if you have a lot of luggage.

Comment: However Kings Cross platform to the Piccadilly Line is not an especially easy walk with a lot of luggage (I learnt this the hard way once as an ambitious student). The walk is several minutes of luggage dragging and involves multiple lifts, and if you go the wrong way by accident, the south end of the platform includes a flight of steps with no lift.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way is probably to get a taxi. The journey time is 44 mins (though probably a bit more allowing for traffic), but there will be very short wait times at Kings Cross and it will drop you at the door of your Heathrow terminal. The cost is about 75 pounds, which split four ways is not bad: for four adults that is actually cheaper than the Heathrow Express.

The next fastest way is to take a taxi from King's Cross to Paddington and then get the Heathrow Express to Heathrow. Taxi fare is going to be about 16 pounds, which split between 4 people is pretty reasonable. The time is about 20 mins for the taxi (add a few minutes of wait time at peak hours), the express time is 15 mins and the max wait for the express is 15 mins. Add five or ten minutes to get from the station to the terminal and it comes in on average at 60-65 minutes. However for four adults this will be more expensive than the taxi option. If any of your party are children then that changes things - children travel free on the Heathrow Express. This contributes less to climate change, if that's significant for you.

As Michael Hampton points out, the tube direct on the Piccadilly line is going to be much, much cheaper than any of the above, and only slightly longer. The journey is around 55 minutes, with maybe five minutes to get to the underground, a five minute wait and 5-10 minutes to get from the underground to the terminal, it's likely to clock in at 70-75 minutes. Hoever its only a few pounds per person, and is undoubtedly the best value for your pound. It's also the most environmentally friendly option.

Comment: There's also the walk from the station / underground station to T2 to consider, both of which are at least 5 minutes, perhaps closer to 10!

Comment: Oh, and at some times of the day, a taxi can be quite a bit slower than train or tube, but lunchtime like the OP has it should be quicker

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is going from King's Cross St Pancras tube station to Paddington tube station first via *Hammersmith & City line or Circle line/Circle line* and then interchange to the Heathrow Express at Paddington rail station. The trip takes about [30-35mins](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/results?IsAsync=true&JpType=publictransport&InputFrom=king%27s%20cross&DataSetsJson=null&DataSetsJson=null&DataSetsJson=null&Modes=tube%2Cdlr%2Coverground%2Ctflrail%2Cbus%2Criver-bus%2Ctram%2Ccable-car%2Cnational-rail%2Criver-tour&Modes=tube%2Cdlr%2Coverground%2Ctflrail%2Cbus%2Criver-bus%2Ctram%2Ccable-car%2Cnational-rail%2Criver-tour&Modes=tube%2Cdlr%2Coverground%2Ctflrail%2Cbus%2Criver-bus%2Ctram%2Ccable-car%2Cnational-rail&From=King%27s%20Cross%20(London)%2C%20King%27s%20Cross%20Station&FromId=1001171&FromId=&InputTo=Heathrow%20Airport%20Terminals%201-3&To=Heathrow%20Airport%20Terminals%201-3&ToId=1000105&TimeIs=departing&Date=20150617&Time=0600&IsMapRequired=undefined&Mode=bus&Mode=tube&Mode=national-rail&Mode=dlr&Mode=overground&Mode=tflrail&Mode=river-bus&Mode=tram&Mode=cable-car&Mode=coach&CyclePreference=AllTheWay&WalkingSpeed=average&WalkingSpeed=average&JourneyPreference=leasttime&InputVia=&Via=&ViaId=&NationalSearch=false&AccessibilityPreference=norequirements&MaxWalkingMinutes=40&SavePreferences=false&IsMultipleJourneySelection=False&JourneyType=&IsCycleHireOriginOrDestination=False&OnChosenOptionScreen=False&IsPastWarning=False&AlternativeTime=0553), plus 5-10 mins from the rail station to terminal 2 and <20mins waiting time (<5mins for tube and <15 mins for heathrow express). The trip costs [£24.5](http://www.thetrainline.com/buytickets/combinedmatrix.aspx?Command=TimeTable#Journey/LONDON%20ST%20PANCRAS%20INTL/HEATHROW%20AIRPORT%20(ANY)/25/06/15/12/30/Dep//////Dep/1/0//).

On the other hand, since you have enough time, I would recommend Michael Hampton's answer. The trip takes half an hour longer but costs only £6 and waits 10mins less.